# Why keywords in member class is not highlighted?

Tags: c++, vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

[image]

Why `private`and `public`in`class hold`is not highlighted?

Comment: Your code won't compile, since you're missing semicolons (and other things).  So the parser running in your IDE cannot correctly identify those keywords.

Comment: Why wouldn't you complete writing the class and save the file using `w!` and see anything changes?

Comment: @Smittey : that wouldn't make much sense.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen : IMHO the parser do not rely on the correct syntax for highlighting. Not sure though !!

Comment: My apologies. I didn't read the question properly first time round :) I take it back

Answer (score 0):

First finish the programme, then save the file as a .cpp file with the following vim command :

```
w your_programme_name.cpp
```

Vim might be applying the current color settings. Try to override the current
color settings with defaults using the below vim command :

```
syntax on
```

Occasionally though, I have seen vim getting confused on what to apply where.
Below is the help text from [Vim Documentation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html). This might be the last resort.

> The colors are wrong when scrolling bottom to top.    Vim doesn't read
>   the whole file to parse the text.  It starts parsing  wherever you are
>   viewing the file.  That saves a lot of time, but  sometimes the colors
>   are wrong.
>
> A simple fix is hitting CTRL-L.
>
> Or scroll back a bit and then forward again.
>
> For a real fix, see |:syn-sync|.
>
> Some syntax files have a way to make  it look further back, see the help for
>   the specific syntax file.  For    example, |tex.vim| for the TeX syntax.